# Run class methods in different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, object, methods

Let's suppose I have this class:

```
public class Myclass {
    method1();
    method2();
    method3();
}
```

I want to know if there's a way to run all 3 methods in different threads simultaneously.

Is there a way to create a class `MyThread` :

```
public class MyThread{
    //implementation
}
```

in way that it can accept as a parameter `myclass::method1()`

so that my main function looks something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Myclass myclass = new Myclass();
    MyThread mythread1 = new MyThread();
    MyThread mythread2 = new MyThread();
    MyThread mythread3 = new MyThread();

    mythread1(myclass.method1()); 
    mythread2(myclass.method2());
    mythread3(myclass.method3());
}
```

I want `mythread()` to RUN `method()` in a thread and NOT use the output of it in a thread.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible. Have you done your research and read up on threading in java? If so, what have you tried? If not, you should.

Comment: I know one possible way is to implement `Runnable` for each method on its own, but I want to get the threads to work on the same object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {
    private MyClass myClass;
    private boolean execMethod1;
    private boolean execMethod2;
    private boolean execMethod3;

public HelloRunnable(MyClass myClass, boolean execMethod1, boolean execMethod2, boolean execMethod3) {
    this.myClass = myClass;
    this.execMethod1 = execMethod1;
    this.execMethod2 = execMethod2;
    this.execMethod3 = execMethod3;
} 
public void run() {
    if(execMethod1) myClass.method1();
    else if(execMethod2) myClass.method2();
    else if(execMethod3) myClass.method3();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    (new Thread(new HelloRunnable(myClass, true, false, false))).start();
    (new Thread(new HelloRunnable(myClass, false, true, false))).start();
    (new Thread(new HelloRunnable(myClass, false, false, true))).start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8 you can do this sort of thing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(MyClass::method1).start();
    new Thread(MyClass::method2).start();
    new Thread(MyClass::method2).start();
}
```

In Java 7 and below there's more to the syntax:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread (new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run ()
        {
            method1 ();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I've only shown one method for brevity - you must repeat everything from `new Thead` through `start()` for each method you want to call.